# Converting MediaWiki to something more portable

Tags: dropbox, wiki, xampp, mediawiki

I was hosting a local MediaWiki using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on a Windows machine. Recently, I've begun using multiple machines and realized that having the wiki run locally on a Windows machine might not be the ideal solution for my documentation needs.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm hoping to use something that could leverage DropBox.

My simple requirements:

- Allows linking between articles.
- Taxonomy that, at the very least, allows multiple categorization.
- Some sort of sensible markup. I do not care for WYSIWYG's but not a deal breaker.

I do not need authentication or anything of that sort. I'd prefer a simple migration but if I have to manually migrate documentation over, it's not that big a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) seems to match your requirements: a wiki in a single HTML file. Many plugins are available.

However you'll have to convert your content (as with any other wiki): there is no "wiki standard".

Answer (score 0):

After trying [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/), [Wikipad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) and some other options, I've settled on [Evernote](http://evernote.com/).

It's something that I've tried in the past but I have not fallen in love with it. However, now that I have a specific goal in mind (documenting my personal network setup), it's actually working quite well so far. I especially like the option of taking pictures of cable connections for future references.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change the formatting, and just need an offline copy of the wiki (without edity powers), why not just make an offline copy with wget or httrack - run it periodically to update the site.

Comment: I do not want a publicly accessible wiki. However, I want it portable. That's why TiddlyWiki and WikiPad (with some way to sync the data between multiple machines---like Dropbox) come in.